# Cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Class *' to 'double []'

Tags: c++

Well, Here is the C++ code I've got here and cant compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int n = 900;
class City{
string name;
double area;
int count, roads;


public:
City() {}
City(string a, double b, int c, int d ) { a=name; b=area; c=count; d=roads;}
string getname() {return name;}
double getarea() {return area;}
int getcount() {return count;}
int getroads() {return roads;}
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& , City& );
friend istream& operator >> (istream& , City& );

};

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, City& a) {
out<<"name "<<a.name<<", area "<<a.area<<", count "<<a.count<< ", roads   "<<a.roads<<endl;
return out; 
 }
istream& operator >> (istream& in, City& a) {
in>>a.name>>a.area>>a.count>>a.roads;
return in;
   }
void fill(int arr[], int size){
ifstream ifs("cities.txt.");
for (int i=0;i<size;i++) 
    ifs>>arr[i];
  }


 void func(City* arr){
ofstream ofs("density.out");
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(arr[i].getcount()/arr[i].getarea()>1000)
        ofs<<arr[i];
}
  }

  int main(){
City* hm;
hm = new City[n];
fill(hm, n);
func(hm);
system ("pause");
return 0;
 }
```

here is the error I get while compiling:

> error C2664: 'fill' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'City *' to 'int
>   []'

somehow I see that, it says something is wrong with the Class 'City *" and int[] array, but can't figure out. I change the 'int' with double but same prob. 
that's problem, otherwise it seems a simple array filling function from file.
any idea what's wrong with it?

So, how would

> void fill(City& arr, int size)
>   's body would like?

Comment: I think the phrase `void fill(City...)'s body would like?` is a little confusing, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void fill(int arr[], int size)` means that you need to pass an array of `int` to `fill`. However, you are passing it an instance of `City`, specifically `hm` in your main.

I am assuming that you are trying to read in a list of `City` descriptions from `cities.txt` (and thus have appropriate stream extraction/insertion operators). Change the signature of `fill` to accept a pointer to `City` objects so that you can fill in an array of `City` objects and not `int`s.

```
void fill(City *arr, int size);
```

Make sure that the argument you pass to `fill` in main is a properly allocated array of `City` objects of size at least `sz` where `sz` is what you pass in as the second parameter. Keep in mind to call `delete []` to free this array that you create.

A more idiomatic approach would be to use `vector<City>` so that you don't have to worry about memory management issues. Your modified `fill` signature would then be:

```
void fill(std::vector<City>& c); // note we no longer need the second argument
```

You will need to `#include <vector>` in order to be able to use `vector<City>` though.

Finally, to take advantage of RVO, simply return a `vector<City>` by value instead of passing it in as a parameter. So, you'd do something like:

```
std::vector<City> fill(); // cleaner, faster
```

Answer (score 0):

`void fill(int arr[], int size)` expects an `int` array. You are trying to pass it a `City` array.

You can either write a new function, `void fill(City& arr, int size)` or you could consider writing a templated function, `template<class T> void fill(T* arr, size)`, etc.

Also consider using `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of naked arrays. Bounds checking and memory management will be vastly easier.

Here's a couple of `fill` examples:

```
// keep reading til we run out of cities in the file
void fill_vector(vector<City>& cities)
{
    ifstream ifs("cities.txt."); 
    City city;

    while (!ifs.fail() && !ifs.bad())
    {
        ifs >> city;
        cities.push_back(city);
    }
}

// only read 'n' cities
void fill_array(array<City, 5>& cities, size_t count)
{
    ifstream ifs("cities.txt."); 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
        ifs >> cities[i];
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about std::vector and std::... yet.

how approximatelly 
that function: void fill(City& arr, int size)

will look like corresponding to my program?

Comment: Couple of functions added to my reply. I've not tested them myself. Checking for both `fail()` and `bad()` might be redundant, but you can check that for yourself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong `fill`. The function you want is the templated version in `<algorithm>`: `void fill (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& value);` (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/)).

So in order to initialize every element with an default `City` object, your call would become:

```
std::fill(hm, &(hm[n]), City());
```

or (more readable and shows intention):

```
std::fill(&(hm[0]), &(hm[n]), City());
```

**Edit:** I see now that I misunderstood your question and that you want to fill your `hm` array with stored objects.

As suggested in other answers, changing the signature of your `fill` function to `fill (City * const arr, size_t const n)` should fix that.